# AMP Cache not getting removed

Tags: amp-html

Issue : 
 Most of my AMP URL has been crawled by Google and showing it perfectly.. But I have made significant changes in AMP template code including adding adsense ads and new menu structure. Even after many days still Google AMP CDN showing old design and content.
I tried and tested few online tutorials but its not working with me.
How Can I remove all AMP cache of my website and store updated one on AMP CDN.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide some example URLs.
Google's AMP cache uses one-behind caching which means that viewing the AMP on the cache should be enough to ensure that the cache contains the latest version of your content.

Answer (score 2):

You may check on this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/update-ping) with steps on how to update or remove content from the Google AMP Cache.

> The easiest way to update the version of any AMP document stored in the Google AMP Cache is to make a new request to access that document using the [AMP Cache URL format](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/overview#amp-cache-url-format). The Google AMP Cache automatically requests the latest version of the AMP document from its origin (provided the previous version of the document has been in the cache for longer than its caching headers allow) and serves the updated version to the next user.

You need to use the `update-ping` mechanism to permanently remove content from the Google AMP Cache after the content has been removed from its origin. Cached content that no longer exists will eventually get removed from the cache; it's just faster to use `update-ping`.

Comment: Tried that and does not work. Google decides when to purge the cache and dislike commands...